# Get array of usernames from @Twitter like string

Tags: php, regex

How do I get an array of usernames from a string tagged like in Twitter with the '@' prefix using regex or similar?

For example:

Input:
`hello @person my name is @joebloggs`

Output (array):

`['person', 'joebloggs']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution

```
@[^\s]+
```

Usage:

```
$string = 'hello @person my name is @joebloggs';
$pattern = '/@[^\s]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @person
    [1] => @joebloggs
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$regex = '~@\K\S+~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the matches in the **[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/3)**.

**Explanation**

- `@` matches the AT (but it will not be returned)
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\S+` matches any non-space characters

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
<?php
$re = "/(?<=@)[^\s]+/";
$str = "asdasd asda 232 @asdasd sd232 soi @other asdnasda asjdajh @asdasd";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

demo here : https://eval.in/173103

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => asdasd
            [1] => other
            [2] => asdasd
        )

)
```